# node dotenv won't work with pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application where locally (without pm2) all the environment variables in the `.env` file work just fine using `dotenv`.

But on the server where I'm using `pm2` to run the app, the environment variables remain `undefined`.

The pm2 commands I'm using to run the app on server are:

```
pm2 start myapp/app.js
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`dotenv` will read `.env` file located in the current directory.

When you call `pm2 start myapp/app.js` it won't search for `myapp/.env`.

```
.env // It will try to load this, which doesn't exist
myapp/
   app.js
```

So you have two solutions

use `path` option:

```
const path = require('path'); 
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '.env') });
```

Or call your script from inside `myapp/`

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: Figured it out before you answered but it's correct. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I have server.js in root and .env in root and pm2 still is sharing the environment variables between my two apis.

Comment: Will dotenv overwrite the process variable set by PM2? eg. `FOO=foo; node dotenvAppThatSetsFooToBar.js` Will `console.log(process.env.FOO)` print foo or bar?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I was still running into problems with this and it turns out dotenv will not overwrite vars which are already set.  There's dotenv-override though which allows overriding. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Thanks so much. It saved me a lot of time!

Comment: This works great, thanks! Though I am not sure why you needed the path lib to concatenate a string. ``require('dotenv').config({path: `${__dirname}/.env`});`` works fine.

Comment: @ChrisBroski because it's bad practice to hardcode directory separators. `path.join` takes care of it, and will work in any OS.

Comment: @marcos-casagrande String literals work in any OS too. I think your claim of what is bad practice is highly debatable.

Comment: I never said string literals do not work on some OS... I said hardcoding directory separator is bad practice. Your code won't work on Windows, my example will, reason why I used `path.join` because it's the universal answer.

Comment: @marcos-casagrande Ah, I understand now. Strangely, the exact line of code in my comment is running correctly on both a linux and windows machine.

Comment: Well your windows might be forgiving but know that it won't work on all cases, so it's always recommended to use path functions to correctly form paths.

Comment: Thank you for this! helped me with this error I was only getting with pm2 "Error: secret option required for sessions"

Comment: Thank you! May I ask How config if ES6 import?

Answer (score 38):

A good pattern here is to remove dotenv from your code and "require" it on the command line.  This makes your code nicely transportable between any environment (including cloud-based) - which is one of the main features of environment variables.

Note: you will still need to install dotenv in your project via npm when running it on a server.

a) code up your .env file alongside your script (e.g. app.js)

b) to run your script without pm2:

```
node -r dotenv/config app.js
```

c) in pm2.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name      : 'My Application',
    script    : 'app.js',
    node_args : '-r dotenv/config',
    ...
  }],
}
```

and then
`pm2 start pm2.config.js`

*note: the use of dotenv/config on the command line is one of the best practices recommended by dotenv themselves*

edit 2021: for completeness - as my answer has got some ticks, I wanted to add a 4th option to the list:

d) combined pm2/env config

```
module.exports = { apps : [{
  name      : 'My Application',
  script    : 'app.js',
  env       : {
    PORT: 5010,
    DB_STRING: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    ...
  },
}]};
```

This will be useful if you are treating your pm2.config as environmental configuration and outside of git etc. It just negates the need for a separate .env, which may suit you. It negates the need for dotenv completely as pm2 injects the env variables into your script's process

Comment: c) does not work for me: `Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv/config'`

Comment: hi, can you please help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617733/issue-with-pm2-and-dotenv-not-working-on-ubuntu-server .   Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @Ivan2h sounds to like you haven't installed dotenv - it still needs to be in your node_modules - npm install dotenv

Comment: you will get error if you don't set `node_args : '-r dotenv/config' `

Comment: thanks @Saifee I've fixed it. Strange I had missed out the -r flag as I do have it in my own config script!

Comment: Option C was best for me. All my settings were already in a `.env` file, and I did not want to manage a `.env` file AND a `pm2.config.js` file. Thanks! <3

Answer (score 17):

you have kill you pm2 process first

try

```
pm2 kill
```

then restart pm2 using

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but it wasnt explained clearly so here is the solution based on
github user vmarchaud [comment](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2529#issuecomment-261488119).
This also fixes the issue people had with @Andy Lorenz solution.

In my case i wanted to create an ecosystem file for multiple apps but i was keep getting

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv/config'
```

The solution was easy. 
You have to declar cwd, aka the project folder where the dotenv/config will be read from.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'app1 name',
    script: 'app1.js',
    cwd: '/path/to/folder/',
    exec_mode: 'fork_mode',
    node_args: '-r dotenv/config',
  }, {
    name: 'app2 name',
    script: 'app2.js',
    cwd: '/path/to/folder/',
    instances: 'max',
    exec_mode: 'cluster',
    node_args: '-r dotenv/config',
  }],
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse `.env` using `dotenv` lib end set them manually in `ecosystem.config.js`

ecosystem.config.js:

```
const { calcPath, getEnvVariables } = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      script: calcPath('../dist/app.js'),
      name: 'dev',
      env: getEnvVariables(),
    },
  ],
};
```

helpers.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');

function calcPath(relativePath) {
  return path.join(__dirname, relativePath);
}

// this function will parce `.env` file but not set them to `process.env`
const getEnvVariables = () => {
  const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(calcPath('.env')));

  const requiredEnvVariables = ['MODE'];

  for (envVariable of requiredEnvVariables) {
    if (!envConfig[envVariable]) {
      throw new Error(`Environment variable "${envVariable}" is not set`);
    }
  }

  return envConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me because I was using cluster mode.

I installed dotenv as dev dependency at the root (I was using yarn workspaces too).

Then I did this:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'path/to/your/.env' })

module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'app',
            script: 'server/dist/index.js',
            instances: 2,
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            instance_var: 'APP_INSTANCE_SEQ',
            // listen_timeout: 10000,
            // restart_delay: 10000,
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same issue as well. My app would run locally but fail when deploying with PM2.

Reading the above, I came up with a super simple fix:

BEFORE:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

AFTER

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({
  path: '../.env'
});
```

*note: ensure that this is the very first piece of code in your app.*

Answer (score 0):

I use a much simpler version of @Marcos answer:

```
.env
app.js
```

for example we need to store token in `.env` file and pass it right to `app.js`:
inside .env

```
token=value
```

inside app.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.token)
```

Also, don't forget. If you add .env file to .gitignore and then `git pull` you repo on VPS or smth, you need to copy .env file manually, otherwise your app won't work.

And in some cases it's important in what area you are using your config, so make sure that `NODE_ENV=production` string is added to your .env file.

After all you could use `pm2 start app.js` right from your app's folder.

Answer (score 0):

This was my project setup..

/src/app.ts

which than compiled into dist folder.

/dist/app.js

my .env file was outside dist folder so it wasn't accessible.

this is the command i tried.
**pm2 start app.js --env=.env**

Comment: Well, did it work?

Comment: Yes. my .env file was located at app.ts file.