# Issue with PM2 and DotEnv not working on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, process, pm2

I know that there are answers for this question, but I don't want to create one more config file and load all the configuration there and run the pm2 process.

```
Project Structure
-----------------
.env
index.js -> server is listening in this file
routes/
models/
middleware/
startup/
package.json
...
```

Inside **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "eventbooking",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^15.0.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "helmet": "^3.18.0",
    "joi-objectid": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.14",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

As you see from my **package.json** file that I am loading the **node -r dotenv/config index.js** file from **scripts > start**

When I run locally with the following command

**npm start**

The project works totally fine.

Now I have deployed the project to the server and there if I manually run

**npm start**

then works fine.

When I install **PM2** in Ubuntu Server in production and do the following steps then it's not working.

Step 1: Mode inside the project folder in the root directory and

```
pm2 start index.js --name "Event Booking"
```

Then getting the following

```
 App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem      │ user │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────┼──────────┤ 

│ index    │ 0  │ 1.0.0   │ fork │ 29897 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 3.7 MB   │ root │ disabled
```

But the project not working. Whats the issue.

Even when I run the following as

```
pm2 start -r dotenv/config index.js --name 'Event Booking'
```

Then getting error as

**error: unknown option `-r'**

Any other solution to run the script with pm2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve a solution.

**Solution 1:**

When running the pm2 process run with the **--node-args** as follows

```
pm2 start index.js --name eventbooking --node-args="-r dotenv/config"
```

You can pass multiple arguments with space separated, other than **dotenv/config** I didn't need much as I am loading everything from **dotenv** package but showing just for demo as follows

```
pm2 start index.js --name eventbooking --node-args="-r dotenv/config --production --port=1337"
```

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively, you can initialize your project with **pm2 init** this will create the pm2 configuration file with name **ecosystem.config.js**

For me for some reasons the **args** under **app** didn't work so I had to add **node_args** again as follows

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "eventbooking",
      "script": "./index.js",
      "node_args": ["-r dotenv/config"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Actually, I am sticking with **solution 1** for cleaner and minimal code mode.

In case if anyone interested with PM2 options then please visit the following link

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the notes from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55853036/2208713. I can see from your question above you are mixing up pm2 syntax with npm. If you take the pattern from my answer you will be able to get this working easily enough - but follow my instructions carefully!

Comment: thank you very much Andy I found some alternative. Please have a look at my solutions. I will be really glad. +1 for helping me out.

Comment: no problem my friend, and glad you got it working.  I personally prefer your solution 2, as all the pm2 parameters are nicely stored in the config js file, but it depends what other tooling you are using to manage your environments.